# Bug in echo command in linux shell?

Tags: shell, echo

There is weird thing i noticed today

If i have file by name **i** or **o** or **e**

and echo any string with any of the above character within square bracet - [] then it always prints only the character

```
$ touch i e o

$ ls -lrh
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 May 23 08:24 o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 May 23 08:24 i
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 May 23 08:24 e


$ echo [offline]
e i o

$ echo [online]
e i o

$ echo [error]
e o

$ echo [soap]
o
```

and if i remove the file everything works fine

```
$ rm -f e i o

$ ls
$ echo [offline]
[offline]

$ echo [online]
[online]

$ echo [error]
[error]

$ echo [soap]
[soap]
```

So what is the relation between echo and these file names ?

Comment: Not a bug in `echo` at all -- everything happening here happens *before* `echo` is started, so `echo` couldn't possibly have anything to do with it. That is to say, your `echo [soap]` is run as `echo o`, because the shell expanded the glob before starting it. Same as `ls *.txt` doesn't pass the `*.txt` to `ls`, but replaces it with a list of files with names ending in `.txt` *before* `ls` is invoked.

Comment: Consider `ls [soap]` as an illustrative example. And run `set -x` to see the commands *as the shell runs them*, so you can see if it's passing the original string to the invoked command, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

The shell performs pathname expansion on the command line arguments. Pathname expansion looks at each *unquoted* argument in turn and tries to replace it with a list of matching filenames. For this purpose the following wildcards apply:

- `*` means 0 or more characters, any characters;
- `?` means 1 character, any character;
- `[`<chars>`]` means 1 character, one of the given <chars>.

If one or more file names match, the command line argument is replaced with the list of matching file names. If no file names match, the command line argument is left as is.

So in your case:

- `[offline]` is an unquoted command line argument, which
- Includes the wildcard `[`...`]`, and
- The files `e`, `i` and `o` match the wildcard, so
- The shell replaces the argument with the list of matching file names.

Morality: Always but always quote the arguments which you don't want the shell to expand. Always say `echo '[offline]'`, never say `echo [offline]`.

Comment: Also, since duplicates aren't kept, `[offline]` is treated as `[ofline]`, which is also the same as `[oenilf]`, etc, because order doesn't matter.