# Why does * put all file names in the argument vector?

Tags: bash, echo

I stumbled upon this while working through the exercises in K&R2. Why does `echo *` prints the names of all files in the current directory? More generally, **when I write a C program that takes command-line arguments, and when I give it `*` as an argument, it puts the names of all files in its parent directory in to the argument vector**. Why does this happen? What is so special about `*`?

I could not find anything about this in the internet.

Comment: How `echo *` is even related to C?

Comment: We literally had a question about why `echo` emits glob results rather than the exact string following its name on the unparsed command line [just this morning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50488590/bug-in-echo-command-in-linux-shell#comment87990669_50488590).

Comment: If you want to use * as an argument you have to put it in single or double quotes.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think echo is written in C. If you read the whole question, you will see the link.

Comment: @MuratGöksel, `echo` is a shell builtin, not an external program -- run `type echo` in bash to have the shell tell you as much. Its behavior is thus defined by the shell language specification; it's only a C question insofar as *any* question about something written in C is a C question (and if we accepted that reasoning, everything with the `python` tag would also get a `c` tag, f/e, since the Python interpreter is written in C).

Comment: More to the point, whether `echo` is internal or external, globbing takes place *before `echo` (or any other regular command) is even started at all*.

Comment: @MuratGöksel, unless your platform is Windows, your program has no control whatsoever about how arguments are expanded before that program is invoked. Expansion is done *by the shell*, outside the program's control.

Comment: @MuratGöksel, ...it also looks like your *real* question (after editing) is whether you can prevent or avoid that expansion. If so, we have quite a number of duplicates on the topic.

Comment: ...for example, [Stop shell wildcard expansion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456403/stop-shell-wildcard-character-expansion), which asks *Is there any way for a compiled command-line program to tell bash or csh that it does not want any wildcard characters in its parameters expanded?*

Comment: ...the important to thing to understand is that programs aren't (at the operating system layer, in UNIX-family systems) given a string with arguments -- the argument vector is passed by the calling program *in vector form*, as you can see in `man execve`. Conversion from a string to a vector is done by the shell, if there *is* a shell -- more reliable ways to start a subprocess with a precise argv don't use one. If you want to control how the shell does that conversion... well, that's what quoting (like `echo '*'`) is for.

Comment: ...now, in *Windows*, the argument list is passed a string, and while the local libc has default parsing available, programs have control over how they parse/expand it... but Windows is a very different beast (and has a ton of inconsistencies on account of this decision, making it very difficult to pass arbitrary data between programs in a safe and reliable way).

Answer (score 1):

This is called **globbing**. [Here's a detailed description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). Other wildcards include `?` for one character, `[abc]` for one of a set of characters, and `[a-z]` for one of a range of characters. This is built into various shells, including Bash.

In response to your comment "I think echo is written in C" — this doesn't matter a bit. Once source code is compiled into an executable containing machine code, it doesn't matter what language it was written in.

Comment: Please make an effort to check for duplicates before answering questions like this -- see [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the 3rd bullet point in the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section.

Comment: I think I phrased it poorly. Please refer to the part in bold.

Comment: If you're invoking your C program on the command line in a shell like Bash, my answer still applies.